# [Glide warn]: Root element must be a existing Html node TypeError: this.root is undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, glidejs

I have one slider included in two pages `index.html`, `about.html`. The `index.html` page slider runs without problem, but another HTML file, `about.html`, has the error:

> [Glide warn]: Root element must be an existing Html node
>   TypeError: this.root is undefined

It seems like this `Glide` can't find elements initialized from that. **How can I resolve this problem?**

More info can be found on [a GitHub issue I filed](https://github.com/glidejs/glide/issues/283), as well as [a related issue posted by another user](https://github.com/glidejs/glide/issues/204).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glide will not initialize for you multiple instances when you passing a selector string as parameters. It will see that this is a string and make a single `querySelector` call.

To initialize multiple sliders with same selector you have to query collection of HTMLElements by yourself and initialize glide on each one individually (in a simple loop).

```js
var sliders = document.querySelectorAll('.glide');

for (var i = 0; i < sliders.length; i++) {
  var glide = new Glide(sliders[i], {
    // options
  });

  glide.mount()
}
```