# JavaScript (glide.js) - Laravel Mix "type=module" needed and why?

Tags: javascript, laravel-mix, glidejs

I am using a Laravel application and Laravel Mix for asset building.

I was trying to use Glide.js this evening and did the following after installing glide.js via npm.

Within my `resources/js/app.js` file I have this contents:

```
require('./bootstrap');

import Glide from '@glidejs/glide'
new Glide('.glide').mount();
```

My `webpack.mix.js` filed which is compiled by Laravel Mix, looks like this:

```
mix.copyDirectory('resources/img', 'public/img')
    .js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .version();
```

When I now load the frontend, my slider does not work - it throws an JS error : `[Glide warn]: Root element must be a existing Html node`

When I change my script tag from:

```
<script src="{{ mix src='js/app.js' }}"></script>
```

To

```
<script src="{{ mix src='js/app.js' }}" type="module"></script>
```

It works - but is this really necessary? I have never read about `type=module` in combination with mix. Is this always necessary once the main js has "import" statements?

Comment: I use Laravel Mix on a daily basis, and have had never used the `type=module`. Your error seems to be something else, maybe see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52692950/glide-warn-root-element-must-be-a-existing-html-node-typeerror-this-root-is

Comment: Yep, it's weird - but I have only one slider on the page and therefore only one element with the class `.glide`

Comment: Yeah I saw that, instead of `{{ mix src='js/app.js' }}`, could you use `{{ asset('/js/app.js') }}` and see if it makes any difference?

Comment: asset is not known here in my antlers template (I use Statamic, so maybe that's why)

Comment: Hmm, maybe try executing the script after the DOM is loaded. Maybe the script is getting called before the element is printed on the DOM.

Comment: Yep, I think it's a race condition and once I use `defer` in my script tag it works as well. So maybe `type=module` does some kind of "defer" as well...

Comment: Yeah it seems like it.